# Xamarin & Visual Studio, Windows Phone & ASP.NET: Is a true single class library possible?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin, portable-class-library

I've currently built a service layer and API which I'm consuming from an ASP.NET website, Windows Phone app, and a Windows 8 metro app - the key to all of them being a project containing model classes which is a portable class library project, and is shared as a reference between all of them. This architecture works fine and without any issues.

However, I've recently started experimenting with Xamarin - specifically the iOS functionality (with a view to moving onto Android later). My initial assumption was that I would be able to utilise this model library as I do with the other projects - however, I've since realised this this isn't the case.

When I first added a reference to my model class library to my Xamarin.iOS project (in Visual Studio), I was greeted by the error:

'The current project does not support references to Portable Library projects'.

Strange - as I thought this would be a scenario that would be supported. I found a post [here](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/xamarinios-with-mvvmcross-in-vs2012.html) which suggested a fix that forced Visual Studio to detec the Monotouch (Xamarin) framework as supporting Portable Library Projects. Seemed to be exactly what I needed - but no. When I added the reference again, I was greeted by a different error:

'The current project's target framework is not compatible with that of the Portable Library project'.

And it suggests I change the target framework in the project properties. Except I can't, as the Xamarin iOS project needs to support Monotouch (and I can't change it to anything else from the GUI anyway). So I tried to change the model library's properties instead - maybe I can do something there. And it looked like I could. I can check Monotouch (Xamarin) as a supported platform here (where Windows phone, Windows store, etc are already checked), but it won't let me save. It just shows the message:

'There is no additional functionality that is supported by the target frameworks you have selected'

After some research, I discovered that the only way Xamarin suggest to share code is to use separate projects with linked code files (so in effect, a pseudo-single code base. Which I have tried and works - but it seems a hack. See here:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options

So is this the only option? Or is there any way to have a *true* single class (model) library across all platforms, including Microsoft and Xamarin?

Answer (score 1):

It is currently possible to use Portable Library Projects - e.g. profile 104 - across all of .Net4.5, WP, WinRT, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS

It is also currently possible to use the output binary assemblies across .Net4.5, WP, WinRT and Xamarin.Android - but not current against Xamarin.iOS.

This situation is changing 'very soon' now with Xamarin adopting full PCL support - see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/the-future-is-portable.html and listen to http://hanselminutes.com/362/ios-and-android-apps-with-xamarin-studio-20-and-miguel-de-icaza

I personally deliver MvvmCross (and a lot of apps that use MvvmCross) using PCLs - and have done for the last 6 months - but there is some setup pain involved in this currently. For some info see my blog:

- http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/cross-platform-winrt-monodroid.html
- http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/xamarinios-with-mvvmcross-in-vs2012.html

I do hope to provide an update on this in the very near future - it should work 'out of the box' soon.

Comment: Interesting - thanks for the info. I've followed the steps here to add a new XML file to the SupportedFrameworks folder:

http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/cross-platform-winrt-monodroid.html

Now I assume when I do that I should go to my PCL project's properties. and add the VS Monotouch profile to the supported platforms? But when I do that, I get the error "There is no additional functionality that is supported by the target frameworks you have selected". Don't support you've any ideas?

Comment: Follow the second link for monotouch, not vsmonitouch - then make sure you choose wp7.5+ and .net4.5+ for platforms

Comment: No - it will work with VSMonoTouch too - I've used that for PCLs through from May 2012 through to Feb 2013 :) Just check that you got your xml files in the right place.

Comment: Thanks Stuart - I'll double check and then come back :).

Answer (score 0):

The future is bright on Xamarin side, as it is going to support .NET 4.5 profile on all its platforms,

http://blog.xamarin.com/brave-new-async-mobile-world/

The only problem as far as I can see comes from Microsoft side, who refuses to unify its own platforms to a common profile (Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 are still messy tailored versions no better than CF or Silverlight in my own situation).

Portable class libraries are out there, but as a library author ([#SNMP](http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com)) I rather build separate project files for my own projects as Xamarin suggests.

Comment: Thanks Lex - it's good to know that it will support the full profile in the future. I do actually see the benefit of using separate project files, but in the case of my classes, they're literally flat models with no special functionality. But if it's the only way, I'll go with the separate projects :).